# SVN svnrdump load - pre-revprop-change hook

Tags: linux, svn, hook

I am trying to migrate a subversion repository from one server to another. I can dump the repository from the old server to a file, but I am having issues with loading the dump file to the new server.

I created a repository on the new server, and added the hook file: /svn/repo2/hooks/pre-revprop-change

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

And I change that file's permissions (I get this when I enter `ls -la`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache   17 Apr  7  2020 pre-revprop-change
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache 2786 Apr  7 14:49 pre-revprop-change.tmpl
```

When I try to load the dump file to the new repository, I enter this command:
`svnrdump load http://myUserName@123.456.78.9/repo2 < fileName.dump --username myUserName`

I get this error:

```
svnrdump: E175008: While handling the 'svn:rdump-lock' property on '/repo2/!svn/bln/0':
svnrdump: E175008: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with no output.
```

As a note that may be relevant, there is another repository that is working on the same server (/svn/repo1) that is working.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup ownership, in this case /var/www/svn is the root directory of my subversion repositories.

> sudo chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn

Answer (score 0):

Regular execution permissions are needed but not enough.  You need to grant the execution in SELinux.to Apache/HTTPD to the script like this.

```
chcon -t httpd_exec_t pre-revprop-change
```